# jquery relative a href="#" remove display block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<li><a href="#section17"><b>Arbeiten</b></a></li>
```

This is the link. When i click this it change the id of the div(#section17) from display none to block.

```
<li><a href="#section15"><b>Feiern</b></a></li>
```

Now if i click on a other link(#section15) it should change the display:block from #section17 to display:none again and the link(#section15) to display block

The page doesnt reload just the url change a little bit.
Can anyone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function () {
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $(addressValue).css("display","block");
    });

</script>;
```

Comment: can you share the html of elements like `section15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/qba7e/

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#section17"><b>section 17</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section18"><b>section 18</b></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section19"><b>section 19</b></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="sections-container">
    <div id="section17">section 17</div>
    <div id="section18">section 18</div>
    <div id="section19">section 19</div>
</div>
```

### JQuery

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    // Prevent jumping to anchor
    e.preventDefault();

    // Hide all other sections
    $('#sections-container > div').css('display', 'none');

    // Show only one we want
    var addressValue = $(this).attr('href');
    $(addressValue).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the link's default behaviour:

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $(addressValue).css("display","block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give all sections a class of `sectionClass` then hide all elements with this class and show the relevant one on click you should be in business.

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".sectionClass").hide();
    $(addressValue).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function HideShow(ctrl) {
            var addressValue = $(ctrl).attr("href");
            $(addressValue).css("display", "block");
        }
    </script>
    <li><a href="#section17" onclick="HideShow(this);"><b>Arbeiten</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section15" onclick="HideShow(this);"><b>Feiern</b></a></li>
```